# Server is not responding due to a long-running script

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have an SSRS report that for some reason isn't running in Internet Explorer. When we run it in Chrome or Firefox, it works just fine, but in IE, it'll run and say "Loading" for a long time and will pop up an error "Server is not responding due to a long-running script."

Other reports seem to work fine in IE, but this one, depending on what parameters you choose, it won't run and will give that error. Upon choosing those same parameters that won't run in IE and running it in Firefox or Chrome, it works fine.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Thank you

Comment: Is it the server not responding, or the browser? While IE is "stuck", can other clients run other reports or even this same report?

Comment: It's the browser, while it's stuck others can still run the report.

Comment: Also to add, this report works fine when I run it in SSMS as well as in Report Builder using those same parameters that are causing IE to freeze up and give that error. So pretty much in IE, some parameters work fine, but certain parameters will cause it to lock up, but it works when I run it in the other mentioned applications.

Comment: Then it's probably an issue with either IE (I've seen some IE patches cause problems for SSRS) or the SSRS plug-in that it's loading. I don't see how this is an issue with the server.

Comment: Yes, I've narrowed it down to most likely being an IE issue since I've had other users test in IE as well with those parameters and it not working but works in other browsers. Just trying to find out what it is about IE that's not working.